# Nested unions in c

Tags: c++, c, nested, unions

I don't understand why the output of following code is 15,15. unions are nested in the code. This question was asked in interview for a post of software engineer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
    union A
    {
        long int y[5];
        union B
        {
            double g;

            union C
            {
                int k;

                union D
                {
                    char ch;
                    int x[5];
                }s;
            }a;


        }b;

    }*p;

    p = (union A*) malloc(sizeof(union A));

    p->b.a.k = 15;

    printf("%d ,%d", p->b.a.s.x[0], p->y[0] );


}
```

This code prints 15,15. Please explain why this prints 15,15 and not garbage, garbage as i had expected? AND WHEN I USE float k instead of int k output is GARBAGE, GARBAGE why this is happening?

Comment: I don't even want to know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: He said it was an interview question, which means that it's intentionally obfuscated and confusing.

Comment: Hint: unions are not structs.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be garbage? &y[0] == &b.a.s.x[0] == &b.a.k. They're all the first element of the type.

Comment: There should be some logic behind getting 15,15 as output I just wanna know that logic If you guys know that

Comment: @user2481909 a union is not a struct, as I've explained. Union members start at the same memory address. They overlap. If you set a single `int` in a union to some value, and the union has an array of `int`s, then the first element in the array will be set to the same value.

Comment: why would somebody want to work someplace where they code like this?

Comment: this code is highly platform depended and it can output garbage on 64 bit machines (`sizeof(long int) != sizeof(int)`) or on big endian machines.

Answer (score 5):

If this union were un-nested, the members would be:

```
    long int y[5];
    double g;
    int k;
    char ch;
    int x[5];
```

On your platform, `long int` and `int` are probably both 4 bytes, so `y[0]`, `k` and `x[0]` all refer to the same integer. So it should be no surprise that they contain the same value.

Comment: It wouldn't matter if `long int` and `int` are the same size with a little-endian architecture.

Comment: or the endianness is correct for direct assignations between `long` and `int` ... +1 anyway.

Comment: If it were "float a" instead of "int k" in my code then output of the code would have been garbage, garbage why so in case of float?

Comment: Because all the values occupy the same memory space, but how the value at that address is interpreted depends on which union member you access via. When you store a float in that location and then use an int member to retrieve it, you'll see the underlying representation of your float value. It's akin to doing `float x = 42; int* xp = (int*)&x; printf("answer to life the universe and everything is not: %d\n", *xp);`

Comment: @kfsone see the code of FastAI below in that code if I replace long a to float a and then assign b=10 and then print value of a it prints 0.00 why???

Comment: Do you understand why `float x = 42; int* xp = (int*)&x; printf("answer to life the universe and everything is not: %d\n", *xp);` does what it does?

Comment: @MarkRansom: It matters if `long int` and `int` are not the same size. If they are not, the greater-addressed bytes of `y[0]` are not initialized or set. Additionally, the behavior of printing the `long int` `y[0]` with `%d` is not defined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, you're right. For some reason I thought it was setting `y`, not reading it. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a union all the things inside overlay in memory.

So:

```
union D
{
    long a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

they will all start at the same spot so anything I put in b will show up in c (and vice versa). If I assign something to a, the first half of its bits will show up in b & c.

I suppose if I did this instead:

```
union D
{
    long a;
    struct ints
    {
        int b;
        int c;
    }
    i;
} NN;
```

THEN if I put something in NN.a the HOB and LOB would show up separately in the ints NN.i.a and NN.a.b.

Back to your example.

Union A only contains y  and b (which is union B). in THE SAME memory overlaying.
 Union B contains the double and Union C...
  Union C contains the int K and union D, etc.

So note now, the vars declared at the beginning are all taking the same memory. In fact since there are no stucts as in my example, every single member starts at the same memory.

Good luck!

Comment: If it were float a instead of long a (in your code) then it would not contain the value with which b or c were initialized , why so???

Comment: @user2481909 -  I'm assuming for the example an long is double the size of an int. A float might take up more bytes than a long. There is a certain way of storing floats in memory (IEEE, binary mantissa+exponent, are some word to google).  Try to find a tutorial that shows you pictures of how UNION lays out in memory, it will help answer the questions you're still having. I tried 'C union struct memory' and got lots of pretty pictures, no 'SQL Union' noise (a little google-fu advice!)